# How to link SFML when linking statically with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to link SFML statically. This isn't really a problem: Just following the instructions on the SFML-Dev site for Visual Studio works without a problem. However, I've found out that the rest of the application (depending on the std-library) still isn't linked statically but dynamically. In order to link this part statically too, I've found on the internet that I need to change the Code Generation to Multithreaded and in some special cases the MFC to use static Windows libraries.

However, this doesn't work. Whenever I try to compile my project with the /MT flag, it gives the following error about 40 times:

> Error LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value
>   'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in
>   AI.obj    Mockfish_2.1_Graphics   C:\Users\olive\Documents\Visual Studio
>   Stuff\Projects\Mockfish_2.1_Graphics\Mockfish_2.1_Graphics\sfml-system-s.lib(String.cpp.obj)  1

However, when I try to compile a project without SFML using the /MT flag, it works without a problem. Is there a way to link the entire solution statically with SFML?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd have to compile SFML on your own with the flag enabled. Although I'm not sure I understand why you want to link the MSVC runtime statically

Comment: Are you compiling on the same version of Visual Studio as the one the library was built from?  You can always use the source codes to build along with your codes, although depends on the licence, some won't let you do this, others require you to link statically or dynamically etc...

Comment: @UnholySheep , tbh I'm not 100% sure. I got the idea of linking every part of the application statically because I thought that some Windows systems lack some dll files that are required for the execution of such an .exe file. Am I wrong about that? Or do I know exactly which dll files I'd have to include in the folder with the exe file?

Comment: The MSVC runtime is usually installed globally for users, as pretty much all native applications use it. If they don't have the one your application requires it is still usually better if they install it themselves (even better would be if your application provided an installer that made sure the required runtime version is installed)

Comment: @UnholySheep thank you!